# Is there any way to access Wifi Signal strength in Swift on iOS 13?

Tags: swift

I'm working on an app that needs to access wifi signal strength. I don't need to publish it to the app store so I don't care if the method is approvable or not. I've looked high and low but can't seem to find a way to get this info. The best I've found is this guide:
https://www.progressioapps.com/get-wifi-information-on-ios-with-swift/

But the statusBar can't be accessed in the same way on iOS 13. Any ideas?